# Tensorflow 2.2 does not find GPU on my Microsoft Windows Surface book 3-- no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

[deviceQuery confirms Computer has Cuda capable device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZetLe.png)
I get this error after seemingly to load cuda files:

```
2020-07-19 17:18:41.922056: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-19 17:18:56.392936: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-19 17:18:56.969124: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
  2020-07-19 17:18:56.976577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: SURFACE-
2020-07-19 17:18:56.980572: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-19 17:18:57.018199: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x25fbcf00ee0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-19 17:18:57.018616: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I checked in my Python Code:`tf.test.gpu_device_name()` and returns nothing.
Also, does not list GPU in `print(device_lib.list_local_devices())`

The code to test is:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
        b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
        c = tf.matmul(a, b)
    tf.print(c)
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
    if tf.test.is_built_with_cuda():
        print("Built with cuda")
    if tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support():
        print('Built with GPU support')
    if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
        print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
    else:
        print("No Installed GPU version of TF")
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Comment: Wadood, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us the code you used that gave the initial error.

Comment: It is Tensorflow 2.2, Cuda 10.1.

Comment: If you have installed CUDA 10.1, the first thing to do would be to [verify the installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#verify-installation).

Comment: Installation @RobertCrovella is verified. Both deviceQuery and bandwidthTest return pass.

Comment: My guess would be then that your surface book is switching the GPU off.  You may wish to learn how to use [optimus profiles](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2615/~/how-do-i-customize-optimus-profiles-and-settings%3F) or there may be  [a surface book setting or control panel that allows you to force the GPU on](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-your-surface-book-use-its-dedicated-gpu-games).

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by adding:
`os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"`